# Iphone: Event Creation using Kal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, calendar, kal

Hi i am in the process of making a tab bar application where one of the tabs is a calendar..

To make the calendar i am using the Kal open source framework
(http://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

I am currently trying to add an event creation button to add events
(exactly like the "+" button on the original iphone calendar!)

Could someone please be kind enough to show how i should do this?

*NOTE: In order to make my question as easy as possible, i am using the "NativeCal" example project that comes with the Kal framework, which does exactly what i want.*

Comment: Any luck?  I'm trying to the same thing (exactly like the "+" button).  I started working on it and then thought that maybe stackoverflow had an idea.  Back to the drawing board!